# How to shift datetime column by -1 and fill the NaT with the diff between the previous two values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a `df` as follows:

```
    start   values
0   2020-03-01 00:15:00 63.2
1   2020-03-01 00:30:00 61.0
2   2020-03-01 00:45:00 58.9
3   2020-03-01 01:00:00 57.0
4   2020-03-01 01:15:00 55.3
5   2020-03-01 01:30:00 53.7
```

I am trying to create a new column called `end` and for that I did:

```
df['end'] = df['start'].shift(-1)
```

which gives the following output

```
    start   values    end
0   2020-03-01 00:15:00 63.2 2020-03-01 00:30:00
1   2020-03-01 00:30:00 61.0 2020-03-01 00:45:00
2   2020-03-01 00:45:00 58.9 2020-03-01 01:00:00
3   2020-03-01 01:00:00 57.0 2020-03-01 01:15:00
4   2020-03-01 01:15:00 55.3 2020-03-01 01:30:00
5   2020-03-01 01:30:00 53.7 NaT
```

I am trying to fill the `NaT` with the diff between the two previous values, i.e, the `NaT` should be

```
2020-03-01 01:45:00 (2020-03-01 01:30:00 + 15 mins (2020-03-01 01:30:00-2020-03-01 01:15:00))
```

I tried:

```
df['end'] = df['start'].shift(-1).diff().ffill()
```

but it gives me the following error:

> 'TimedeltaProperties' object has no attribute 'strftime'

What's the mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df["end"] = df.start.shift(-1).fillna(df.start + df.start.diff())
```